# on refinance does previous company return ALL extra money

Tags: united-states, mortgage, refinance

I am trying to do a refinance and the new company is keeping some buffer amount to pay to the previous company. The previous company also has some escrow balance. At same time the new company is taking some time to send payoff amount to the previous company and the 15 grace days are coming near and automated payment has gone through, and not sufficient time to talk to the new compnay to get new payoff statement ( as it will again delay the process).

so wondering if ( and when) all three ( extra by new company+ Escrow + extra month paid) components will be refunded by the previous company or I have to fight for it.

Comment: This is very confusing. Please specify more details.

Answer (score 1):

Eventually you will get all your Escrow money from the original mortgage holder.  In the short term you may have to pay out of pocket for items that are due now; or the new company may raise your escrow portion of your payment to cover these expenses.  It is impossible to know because the policies of both the new and old mortgage holders may have very different policies and timelines for payoffs and refunds.

It is likely that your new mortgage holder paid too much to make sure that the old mortgage is paid in full.  The old mortgage holder will probably add any excess pay off to your escrow balance and refund it within their allotted time frame.  My guess would be about 30 days.

If one can, and is responsible with money, it is always best to do your own escrow.  I believe that this is only available to people who put down at least 20%.  However, policies change over time and vary by company.